# send WM_PAINT command from own program

Tags: visual-c++

How to programmatically send WM_PAINT from my c++ program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[InvalidateRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, and if you want to ensure the paint is done before the code continues you need to call `UpdateWindow()` as well.

Answer (score 4):

[SendMessage(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Can also be used to send messages to other processes (Inter Process Communication)